# Where does one extend a Cambodian visa in Sihanoukville? What is considered a reasonable price?

Tags: visas, visa-extensions, cambodia, sihanoukville

I am with my family in Sihanoukville, Cambodia, and this is a really nice place (not in a sense of cleanliness but rather in the 'simple life' kind of feel, which is extremely refreshing).

Upon landing we got ourselves E-class visas, which in theory can be extended indefinitely.

[image]

As I understand there are agencies that can handle visa extensions. However I wouldn't want to entrust our passports to someone not reputable. Also, I understand prices can vary greatly (like they do on most goods in Cambodia for naive tourists).

**Where does one extend a Cambodian E-class visa in Sihanoukville? What is considered a reasonable price? How long does it usually take? Are there risks or things to look out for?**

Comment: Have you visited the Cambodia forum on TripAdvisor?  There are threads about renewals, including one about 40 passports being stolen enroute from Sihanoukville to Phnom Penh for visa renewals.  You might ask there about agency recommendations, as many posters are either local expats or frequent visitors.

Comment: @Tom Hi Tom, that TripAdvisor post is the reason I asked this question, lol...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went to [Expats and Locals Living in Sihanoukville Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/groups/sihanoukvilleexpats/?fref=nf) and asked this same question so far I got two names that people swear by.

[Ana travel](http://anatravelandtours.com/contact-us-2/) - I called them and they do speak 'understandable English' their rate is 5$ + visa cost, turnaround time is one week.. Their rating is really bad on Google Maps ([2.8](https://www.google.com.kh/maps/place/Ana+Travel/@10.6093513,103.5213128,17.75z/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x3107e1ecf009641f:0xfc9fbecafe020c67!8m2!3d10.6097339!4d103.5227155!9m1!1b1)), but everyone [on Facebook seems to trust them](https://www.facebook.com/groups/sihanoukvilleexpats/permalink/1567774976570824/) and blame some fake impostor company.

[Mottah Travel](http://www.mottah.com/) - Second agency recommended by a few.

You need to bring your passport and money to the agency.